# Activiti workflow and Orbeon XForm Integration

Tags: orbeon, activiti, xforms

I have to integrate Orbeon Xforms with Activiti workflow engine.

Has anybody done this in the past?

How to initiate the Activiti workflow from the Orbeon forms?

I have checked on internet but nobody seems to have integrated the call from Orbeon Xforms to Activiti to start the process instance. The Orbeon XForms has provided REST API but its only supported for XML message and there is no support for JSON parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any publically available integration between Orbeon Forms and Activiti. However, as you noticed, Orbeon Forms can submit the data entered by users in forms as XML to an endpoint you provide, which can be the basis of an integration with Activiti.

And you're correct, at this point Orbeon Forms is only able to send data as XML, and there is an [RFE for sending data as JSON](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2109). But I would assume using XML wouldn't be a problem for Activiti.

Comment: In this case do you suggest any other workflow engine to integrate orbeon form workflow. Activiti dont support XML since all its services are REST JSON based.

Comment: @ShaileshK Is that a new thing in Activiti? From what I am reading (e.g. on http://forums.activiti.org/content/activiti-516-rest-api-returning-xml-not-json), its services support both XML and JSON. I am missing something?

Comment: the page you have inserted is not working.. page not found... i believe activiti is designed for REST based services only and some of the API might result in XML output as a side effect of using Rest based framework.

Answer (score 0):

An orbeon integration with Activiti is possible. Look at this post here: http://forums.activiti.org/content/orbeon-xform-integration-activiti-workflow

It is right that Activiti only supports JSON. But with a custom formHandler, you could receive the XML posted by orbeon, parse the process variables, start a process inatance and write the updated variables back to the Activiti database. I just did a prototypical proof of concept about this. In this servlet, you can use the Java APIs of Activiti.

You could realize it like this:
1. Display an orbeon form which has fields for the initial process values
2. Submit those values to a custom servlet
3. The servlet parses the orbeon xml form data and extracts the typed in values
4. Use the Activiti Java API wihtin your servlet to start a process instance with the values extracted from the orboen xml
5. If the instance was started correctly, send a HTTPStatusCode 200 back to orbeon.
6. Close the orbeon form.

Best regards
Ben

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have done this integration now both with java servlet as well as WCF service in between Orbeon form and Activiti workflow engine.